# How I set my tableview's action buttons alignment vertical in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, tableview

How I set my tableview's action buttons alignment vertical in Swift 3?

[This is my tableview's action buttons looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVmQu.png).
Always this is [look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrE2M.png) This is horizontal and I want to alignment to vertical. How I do this?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
     let RowAction1 = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "action1", handler:{action, indexpath in
     print("action1")
     })
     RowAction1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.298, green: 0.51, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0)

     let RowAction2 = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "action2", handler:{action, indexpath in
     print("action2")
     })
     RowAction2.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.28, green: 0.851, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0)

     let RowAction3 = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "action3", handler:{action, indexpath in
     print("action3")
     })
     RowAction3.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.298, green: 0.81, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0)

     let RowAction4 = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "action4", handler:{action, indexpath in
     print("action4")
     })
     RowAction4.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.298, green: 0.851, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0)

     return  [RowAction1, RowAction2, RowAction3, RowAction4]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a `CustomCell` and use `AutoLayout`? Like this example I created below:

[image]

So you basically create a custom cell inside your `tableView` in your Storyboard and then use it:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomExampleCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomExampleCell
```

You can download the example project I created for you [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zd2ovqp8vrdoouq/CustomCell.zip?dl=0).

**Update**
To use the built in methods in Swift for the Swipe accessibility use the following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "More") { action, index in
        print("More")
    }
    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
        print("Share")
    }
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        print("Delete")

    }
    more.backgroundColor = .gray
    share.backgroundColor = .blue
    delete.backgroundColor = .red
    return [delete, share, more]
}
```

Comment: Then checkout my example of how to use AutoLayout to style the buttons.

Comment: Is this button which open when we swipe to cell?

Comment: No these are custom button that I have created in the cell.

Comment: Ok. I dont want to buttons on my cell. I want to when i swipe to cell open my options buttons.

Comment: @HiKa, ok you were not clear about that in your question. Checkout the updated code in my answer and it will give you what you need.

Comment: @HiKa, if my answer was useful, click the upvote button to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use stackView with Horizontal alignment :)

https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Comment: Is there a solution in tableView's methods or functions? I mean programmatically.

Comment: The stackView is fully customizable in code as well.... just setup the property .aligment to .horizontal I guess

Comment: But I don't really see how writing whole UI in code is useful. If you need so badly the cell pushed away, make custom xib for it...